# how to get 2 ways pullToRefresh in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone, pull-to-refresh

how to get 2 ways pullToRefresh in codenameone ?

I can add pullToRefresh from top by using the following codes

```
f.getContentPane().addPullToRefresh(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                String count = " " + f.getContentPane().getComponentCount();
                f.addComponent(0, new Button("Button " + count));
                f.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

And I want to add pullToRefresh from Bottom of form , how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add pull to refresh to the bottom of a form. Its not a UI paradigm that applies to the bottom. However, you can get an infinite scroll which I assume is what you really want: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/09/till-the-end-of-the-form.html

Comment: how can we find whether user pull from top of form or bottom of form ?
is there any method to detect it?

Comment: No. Read the article I linked which shows how to detect that the user reached the bottom, not pulled the bottom.

Comment: yeah it adds components to form until end of bottom is reached
and I want to add items to list until and how do I detect whether end of bottom is reached and How can I use InfiniteScroolAdapter in list

Comment: The InfiniteScroolAdapter works for containers, lists don't need that. Just use the model to fetch whatever you need dynamically e.g. see our cloud list model https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/cloud/CloudListModel.java